# Error message - 'rank' expects maximum '0' number of parameters

Tags: azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I'm not sure what this means, but I have a simple flow here that aggregates Region and the sum(Sales). When I want to do a ranking by sum(Sales) Partitioned by Region it gives me this strange error. 'rank' expects maximum '0' number of parameters

Here are my captures.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhTIO.png)
[image]

[image]

[image]

I"m not sure what the problem is. I don't have a parameter called Totals saved either.

Answer (score 1):

rank() does not take any parameters. Also, you may find using the Rank transformation is easier.

Comment: rank() is a windowing function.  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Totals) would likely be the expression within SQL that may(?) do what you want.